# "Lighting up the blocks around him"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am not sure I am reading a sentence right in this passage:

> Chang Lee gripped his fingers tighter around the gun and screamed at potential looters from the rooftop of the small strip mall where he stood. The 35-year-old had never held a firearm before the LA riots. **Lighting up the blocks** around him, Lee could smell the fires burning in Los Angeles' Koreatown. ([source](https://www.cnn.com/2017/04/28/us/la-riots-korean-americans/index.html))

"Lighting up the blocks" does not seem to make much sense to me. A "block" is a residential/commercial area delineated by streets. I don't think the subject of the sentence, Chang Lee, is capable of "lighting up the blocks." During the LA riots buildings were set ablaze by protesters. The sentence seems to be a mistake unless "blocks" here refers to something else. What is this sentence saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the fires that he could smell were lighting the blocks around him. The phrase modifies "fires". Put in simpler word order,
"Lee could smell the fires burning in Los Angeles's Koreatown that were lighting up the blocks around him."

Comment: Ohh a dangling modifier? It crossed my mind but I thought it'd be way too dangling for the sentence to be grammatical.

Comment: I don't think it's technically dangling, since it has a clear referent in the sentence. It's displaced, sort of.